# Get document link from search results

Tags: search, library, share

The user wants to search for a doc in library, then get a shareable link. In a library view there are options to get a link to a document for sharing.

But when the user searches the library (365 / New experience), and gets a "search results" view, there is no UI to get a link.

If they open the doc in Word online there is a share button that does nothing.

The only workaround I have is not to use the search. If they want to share they have to filter or sort to find....

The other workaround is to switch the library view to classic experience. Then the functionality is present.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the elipses (... ) next to the title, a hover panel appears.  The SHARE link will provide you with what you are looking for.  Please see the image below:

[image]

EDIT __________________________________

In the search results view, when you hover over an item, you also get the hover panel which provides the same as above.

Comment: Thanks Martin, just updated the question. Looks like you're using SP 2013? Sorry but I should've given my version which is there now. It's SP Online 365 with the library in "new experience" as opposed to "Classic experience". We also have 2013 on prem here and it does work as in your screenshot.

Comment: John, I have SharePoint Online as well.  When you say you search in a Document Library, do you mean you filter?  I don't have the search box available in my library, but I do have a filter.

Comment: Search, not filter. For filter and sort there functionality is available so that could be a workaround. Or revert to Classic experience.

Comment: I've never even noticed the search box on the left!  If you click the ellipse to the right of the title and click preview, one of the options on the preview menu is copy link, but this isn't a real solution, obviously.